# Does useState hook change the value of the state

Tags: reactjs

I just started React, and in this Item list tutorial I have some question about updating the states of the item. Also, I'm using functional component .So in app.js

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Banana',
    bought: false
  },
 ...
])
```

Then I have a function in app.js to update the bought to true or false when I check a box

```
// The id is passed in from Item.js down below
const markBought = (id) => {
  setItems(
    items.map(
     item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        /// If bought is false, checking it will make it true and vice versa
        item.bought = !item.bought; // (1)
      }
      return item; // (2)
    })
  );
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Items items={items} markBought={markBought}></Items>
  </div>
);
```

The teacher said we are using something called Component Drilling. So in Items.js, we map through every item to display them one by one, but I don't think it is neccessary to show.

Finally in Item.js

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={() => props.markBought(props.item.id)} />
{props.item.title}
```

The application worked perfectly, but it's a little bit confusing for me. So:

1. In app.js, after we change the bought status, shouldn't we also need to return item, the same way we return the item if the condition is false? Why only return the item when if is wrong, but when it is right we only change it without a return?
2. I read that map will not modify the array, so markBought function should create a new items array, with the bought modified already, but what happens to this array, how do React know to "props" this to item.js, rather than the ones I hard coded?

Sorry if this is a little bit long, any help will be really appreciated. Thanks for reading

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's generally best to keep your post to one question at a time. with regards to your first question, the line `return item` will always get called no matter if the condition is true. Perhaps you are confusing that if you had `if` and `else` wrapping your return, but this code does not.. your second question is simply best answered by reading the official react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: To your first question, your map function always returns the item regardless of whether the if condition is satisfied. Execution would only stop if you put another return statement inside the if.

Comment: The way you use map you are mutating the array and you should not do that. If you want to change one item in an array with map you shuuld copy that one item and change that copy, short syntax for this is the spread operator: `copy = {...original: changed:'other value'}` For a full working example you can check my answer and comment to it if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating an item in your map, if you optimized your Item component to be a pure component then that component won't re render because of the mutation. Try the following instead:

```
//use useCallback so marBought doesn't change and cause
//  needless DOM re renders
const markBought = useCallback(id => {
  setItems((
    items //pass callback to the setter from useState
  ) =>
    items.map(
      item =>
        item.id === id
          ? { ...item, bought: !item.bought } //copy item with changed value
          : item //not this item, just return the item
    )
  );
}, []);
```

Here is a full example:

```js
const { useCallback, useState, useRef, memo } = React;
function Items() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Banana',
      bought: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Peach',
      bought: false,
    },
  ]);
  const toggleBought = useCallback(id => {
    setItems((
      items //pass callback to the setter from useState
    ) =>
      items.map(
        item =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...item, bought: !item.bought } //copy item with changed value
            : item //not this item, just return the item
      )
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          toggleBought={toggleBought}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
//use memo to make Item a pure component
const Item = memo(function Item({ item, toggleBought }) {
  const renderedRef = useRef(0);
  renderedRef.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>bought: {item.bought ? 'yes' : 'no'}</div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleBought(item.id)}>
        toggle bought
      </button>
      <div>Rendered: {renderedRef.current} times</div>
    </div>
  );
});

//render the application
ReactDOM.render(<Items />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is a broken example where you mutate the item and won't see the re render even though the state did change:

```js
const { useCallback, useState, useRef, memo } = React;
function Items() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Banana',
      bought: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Peach',
      bought: false,
    },
  ]);
  const toggleBought = useCallback(id => {
    setItems((
      items //pass callback to the setter from useState
    ) =>
      items.map(
        item =>
          item.id === id
            ? ((item.bought = !item.bought),item) //mutate item
            : item //not this item, just return the item
      )
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            toggleBought={toggleBought}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(items)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
//use memo to make Item a pure component
const Item = memo(function Item({ item, toggleBought }) {
  const renderedRef = useRef(0);
  renderedRef.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>bought: {item.bought ? 'yes' : 'no'}</div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleBought(item.id)}>
        toggle bought
      </button>
      <div>Rendered: {renderedRef.current} times</div>
    </div>
  );
});

//render the application
ReactDOM.render(<Items />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your enthusiasm. Why is it bad to mutate the original arrays in this situation? I thought map always return new array with modified value, but in this case do you mean it actually changed the original value, and not creating the new array like it's supposed to? These codes come from the tutorial itself, and I just started so what you are saying is a little bit hard for me. But thank you very much again.

Comment: @GoldExperience You should never mutate local state or redux state in React. React would not detect state changes when you mutate, I added a broken (mutate) example to the answer and you see it breaks. Map does return a new **array** but points to the same items and you mutate the item. If this is from a tutorial then I suggest using another tutorial and maybe notify the author about the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to Stackoverflow.

1. You are always returning the `item`. You just have an `if` statement that will change the bought state and `item` will get returned even if the condition above was false, which is the correct way of doing.
2. Map will indeed not modify the array but return a new one. If you want to get that returning array you could simply do :

```
const myNewArray = items.map(...)
```

The way this new `array` is getting to your other component is because this new `array` is given to your `useState()`.
You see `setItems()` ? This will set your state and `Item.js` will automatically be updated.
That is what is so great about react. All components that are served from `state` will be updated once this `state` is updated.

Comment: It's not the correct way of doing, the correct way would be `items.map(
        item =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...item, bought: !item.bought }
            : item
      )` The way OP is using map the item will be mutated `item.bought = !item.bought` will mutate the array returned by map and the original array (modified is what you want either way but not mutation). The only valid point you made is that map will return a new array but since OP mutates the Item will not be re rendered if it's pure (when you optimize the callback)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I thought return belongs to an else somewhere, but it seems like it will always return todo regardless of condition. Your second answer makes a lot of sense to me being new to this, so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your map function always returns an item. It just modifies the item first if the item you're modifying matches the id of the item currently being mapped. Map returns a new array of items (even if it doesn't change anything), which causes useState to see a new value. By default, in React, the check for updates isn't very clever - it's just checking if `oldValue === newValue`.

For primitives like strings, object equality tests return true for two separate objects, as long as their values match.

```
"foo" === "foo"  // => true
```

However, this isn't true for object or arrays. Two different arrays containing the same values will *not* compare as equal (because Javascript isn't comparing their contents, but rather their object IDs):

```
["foo"] === ["foo"]  // => false
```

So, when you `map` your `items`, you get a new array object (because recall: `map` collects the return values of the callback function into a new array), which will *never* match the previous value of `items`, so every call to `setItems` will cause React to say "hm, my previous `items` isn't the same object as my new `items`, I must re-render this component".

Comment: It won't re render if you optimize (it will re render list but not the items). This is because OP mutates the item with matching id. Try the code in my answer with `items.map(item =>
        item.id === id
          ? ((item.bought = !item.bought), item)
          : item
      )` (the mutating code from OP). You can console.log items in list and see it's changed but the item will not re render because it's a pure component and it's props.item has been mutated, not re referenced.